# Redirection using meta tag

Tags: php, redirect, header, meta

I am developing an online shop and when the user's identification is correct, I redirect the user to other page (for example, to google):

```
if(UsersManager::getInstance()->checkIdentification($_POST['userAdmin'], $_POST['passAdmin'])){
    $_SESSION['user']  = $_POST['userAdmin'];
    $_SESSION['lastConection'] = time();
    header('Location: http://www.google.es');
    die();
}
```

I upload this code to my server and it works. I have tried in other server, but the redirection does not work.

Also, I have tried to redirect using this code

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.google.com">';
```

and removing

```
header('Location: http://www.google.es');
die();
```

Neither using meta tag, nor header() works. In my server works fine. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Is that your actual code? Why would your shopping thing redirect to Google? Also the meta tag is nothing more than a workaround, still depends on where you output it. Show the final HTML. And why `Refresh` instead of `Location`?

Comment: No, this is not my real code, is an example (really, my code redirect to "adminMenu.php"). I also have tried using "Location", but does not work. I cannot redirect to other url. Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 3):

Please, try display errors, **probably** appears output buffering warnings. 
Add this at top

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
```

P.S: using meta tags for redirection like you're trying to, isn't a good pratice.

Comment: Please just real answers to the answer section!

Comment: I know that using meta tags for redirection is not a good practice, but I tried it because the other way to redirect, does not work. In the log file doesn't appear anything.

Comment: @AndreyKnuppVital, now I can't, because it is not our server and we must ask for code uploading. When I test it, I will post here the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look into why header(); isn't working.  But A quick fix could be

```
    if(UsersManager::getInstance()->checkIdentification($_POST['userAdmin'],         $_POST['passAdmin'])){
        $_SESSION['user']  = $_POST['userAdmin'];
        $_SESSION['lastConection'] = time();
        header('Location: http://www.google.es');
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        window.location = "http://www.google.es/"
        //-->
        </script>
        <?php
        echo "<a href=\"http://www.google.es\">If your browser didn't redirect you click here.</a>";
        die();
    }
```

Javascript should redirect every one that header() doesn't work for.

If they have javascript disable it gives them that link.  Make it a pretty link though ;]

Comment: We have implemented that and didn't work neither. Could be the server configuration?

Comment: javascript is browserside not server side.  So, it should always work.  Are you sure your script it working correctly?  Maybe your class is not working correctly.    Try using a brand new script and just testing . header('Location: http://www.google.es');  and another one with  just the javascript.  If those work its probably your class.